# Debugging a SQL Query

Tags: sql, debugging, sql-server-2008

Does SQL Server 2008 have a built in debugger? I've got a stored procedure that returns an error if it is fed a string of alphabetic characters (as opposed to numeric) and I'd like to be able to determine what line it gets to before returning an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio can debug stored procedures in SQL Server 2008. Open your stored procedure, and instead of hitting the "execute" button (the red exclamation mark) hit the "debug" button (the green "play" arrow).

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1695

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can debug SQL stored procedures, functions, triggers, etc.

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1695

Answer (score 1):

I would add PRINT 'Checkpoint A passed' type statements at various points to see how far it gets.. the output would appear on the Messages tab.  It's a lame way of debugging, but it works.

```
insert into blah blah blah

print 'Passed the insert'

select blah

print 'Passed the select'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Transact SQL Debugger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646008.aspx)
I've never used it but remember reading about it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
N'' +[TitleOfCourtesy]+ N'' +[FirstName]+ N' ' +[LastName]+ N'there are ' +abs(datediff(day,dateadd(year,(year(getdate())-year([BirthDate])),[BirthDate]),getdate()))+ N' days left untill your birthdate'
```